# Select unique values from Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below data in DB.

```
CODE    Material    Price   Date 
111     XYT         1       1/1/2019
111     SFH         4546    1/1/2019
444     XYT         4546    28/4/2019
676     TYT         563     28/9/2019
676     SFH         4546    1/1/2019
676     XYT         1       1/1/2019
```

I need to get only single or a top value from the column CODE and its corresponding data in rest of the column.

Output needed :

```
   CODE    Material     Price   Date 
    111     XYT         1       1/1/2019    
    444     XYT         4546    28/4/2019
    676     TYT         563     28/9/2019
```

Tried using DISTINCT in various way but I was not able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You need `row_number()` :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by code order by date desc, price);
```

You can also use subquery :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by code order by date desc, price) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

use row_number()

```
select * from (
select * ,row_number() over(partition by code order by dateall desc, price) as t from tab) as ntab where t=1
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ea612f903f8b5dcf150b6dc1b026f2cd)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate table of codes, you might find that `apply` works well:

```
select t.*
from codes c cross apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from t
      where t.code = c.code
      order by t.date desc
     ) t;
```